# Not able to find a particular regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my regex `/(.+)(\.|::)(\S+)\Z/`. 
User enter function.[] 
 Output $1 as function and $3 as []
user enter function[] 
 output nil  
 The desired output is $1 as  function and $3 as []. 
Any guesses how can I alter the above regex to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `match` method to set `$1` and `$3`:

```
/(\w+)(\.|::)?(\S+)\Z/.match('mongo.[]')
$1 # => mongo
$3 # => []

/(\w+)(\.|::)?(\S+)\Z/.match('mongo[]')
$1 # => mongo
$3 # => []
```

Comment: I am actually doing the same, the question is how should I alter the above regex to get in the second case also S1 as x and $3 as [].

Comment: @DeependerSingla in that case use `/(.+?)(\.?)(\S+)\Z/`. This works for both of your cases.

Comment: Its working with it bit there is one problem in suppose it is like mongo[] then it should give $1 as mongo and and $3 as [] but it is giving $1 as m and and $3 as ongo[] so first group should be ultra greedy only.

Comment: @DeependerSingla Updated. If you have other examples this doesn't apply to, then you really need to precisely describe, preferably in another post, the most general string you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `/(.+)(\.|::)*(\S+)\Z/`?

The asterisk that I added means zero or more.

Or `/(.+)(\.|::)?(\S+)\Z/`,

The question mark means zero or one.

Comment: No it will split the first case in wrong also the second one.